# Как в Sphinx выбрать все пустые значения атрибута sql_attr_multi если он задан как uint?

Tags: база-данных, веб-программирование, sphinx

В индексе Сфинкса есть атрибут **sql_attr_multi *uint***, который для некоторых записей содержит набор чисел, как и полагается, а для остальных записей он пуст. Как правильно составить запрос, чтобы получить записи/строки для которых **sql_attr_multi *uint*** пуст?

Ниже указан запрос, который выдает в ошибку **unsupported filter type null on MVA column**:

```
SELECT * FROM myIndexSphinx WHERE myAttrMultiUint IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *, LENGTH(myAttrMultiUint) c FROM myIndexSphinx WHERE c=0;
```